# Hide flexbox items based on a condition(Angular 8)

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

How should I go about hiding and showing items in a flexbox container if they've reached the end of that container?

So when the items reach the end of the container, hide the items but create a button that when clicked will display the rest of the hidden items.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you have tried. This will increase your chance to get an appropriate answer. It also helps you solving the question yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I found a solution but will be sure to include a reproducible example next time.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need, I see 2 solutions:

- In a CSS solution, just give your container a fixed size, and let items overflow, but hide them using `overflow: hidden`. You may then add an ui action to add/remove a css class that would remove the size constraint, so that all items are displayed. There is no simple way to know whether a component is overflowing, however, and your button to show all element will be visible at all time.
- In a javascript  solution, you would need to get your container element instance, get its size and its children size, then check whether items are overflowing. You can then control whether the button should be visible or not.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Ended up using NgAftercontentchecked that called a function with @hostlistener(window:resize) decorator that would count the items based on offsetTop property. It was actually a lot more complicated than I thought because I had to account for browser responsiveness.